# When to create multiple projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm often wary of creating multiple projects in Eclipse. Let's take a scenario:

- There is a main J2EE project, which has all the business logic, render GUI etc
- Then there is one more supporting project, which basically has only the Hibernate POJO and Hibernate related configuration stuff

This means the Hibernate project jar will need to be placed in the main project to test it, every time there is a change.

What are the disadvantages?

- Smallest of change in the class, you need to build the jar all over again and transfer to the server
- You can't directly only transfer the class files, you have to build the complete jar again
- In remote debug mode, edits will not hot replace the class files from Hibernate project, big pain to transfer jar and restart server all the time

What are the advantages?

- If I had to split my J2EE project into 2 project to separate concern tomorrow, I can directly copy the DB part, i.e Hibernate jar and start using split projects

So now my question:

- Is there a guide line on when to to create a new project instead of a new package?
- In the cases like above, would it be a good idea to merge both in one project to resolve 3 disadvantages and contain one advantage?
- What is the industry standard? Best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more you can separate your projects, the better.

As soon as you can establish a clear dependency separation, move it out into its own project. As it grows, this will enable you to reuse code easier in other projects.

Comment: Don't you think, the more you separate, the more trouble it is for the developer to keep tossing the jars around, esp in Java?

Comment: Most definately not, because developers should not be tossing them around. They should be integrated into a build and deploy system (there's good free ones, like Hudson or Cruise Control, or proprierity ones like AnthillPro or Build Forge, and others). At this point, the jars are managed by the tools, and the developers only worry themselves with how the code needs to work.

Comment: Problem is every time a jar is changed, the server needs to be restarted, which is infinity times boring and time consuming. Hot code replacement is a savior for Java guys, but it doesn't work in case of jars. Tools like Hudson et al. are good the project in general, but cannot be used for quick dev testing. It doesn't seem good when you make a change of 1 line and wait for >3 minutes to build and deploy your changes for a quick dev test.

Comment: You should have some kind of build script (Ant, etc) that is capable of building in your dev environment (ideally, the same script the QA and Prod environments use, for consistency.) This build script can easily be set to not rebuild jars with unchanged code files. Having smaller jar files will actually increase your build time, since it has smaller jars to build.

Comment: Yes, however we can't avoid the restart of the server, can we?

Comment: There are some servers (we use Felix at work) that allows hot swaps of jars. You only need to reload the service for the jar in question, and perhaps any services that depend on that service. But the entire server needn't restart.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, if you have different layers, it's avisable to put the layers in different projects. This gives a little extra motivation to keep the layers separat, talk through interfaces and avoid circualar dependencies between layers (projects can't depend on each other!)

I often introduce one specialized project that contains all libraries and resources for the entire application. Maybe another one that is only used to build and deploy the application (the ant/maven build scripts, the product definition in case of RCP applications). And finally, think about defining all test cases in separate projects. Test sometimes need special libraries and resource files (logger configs, database dumps with test data) and those files shouldn't mix up with the applications config files and libs.